# Insert into SQL Server database via Powershell - no error display but no data was inserted in target database

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

The goal of the script shown here is to get data from table 1, and then store it in an array and insert it into table 2. The script runs without error, but no data is inserted into table2.

Script:

```
$Connection = Connect-SQLServer -InstanceName "Local\TestSchema" -DatabaseName "TestDB" -IntergratedSecurity $true

$Results = Invoke-SQLSelect -Connection $Connection -SelectStatement "Select * from [FileInformation]"

foreach ($i in $Results)
{
    $GetTest = $Results #| where-object {$_.id -eq 6}
    write-host "ID:"$i.id
    write-host "FolderPath:"$i.FolderPath
    Write-host "File:"$i.FileName
    Write-host "LastWriteT:"$i.LastWriteTime
    Write-host "CreateT:"$i.CreateTime
    Write-host "FileSZ:"$i.FileSizeinKB
}

$DataArray = @()
#adding to array

foreach ($i in $Results)
{
    $DataArrayLine = new-object PSObject
    $DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ID" -Value $i.id
    $DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FolderP" -Value $i.FolderPath
    $DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "File" -Value $i.FileName
    $DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LastWriteT" -Value $i.LastWriteTime
    $DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CreateT" -Value $i.CreateTime
    $DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FileSZ" -Value $i.FileSizeinKB

    $Results += $DataArrayLine
}

$DataArray 

ForEach ($b in $DataArray)
{
    $id = $b.id -as [int]
    $FolderP = $b.FolderPath
    $File = $b.FileName
    $LastWriteT = $b.LastWriteTime -as [datetime]
    $CreateT = $b.CreateTime -as [datetime]
    $FileSZ = $b.FileSizeinKB

    Invoke-SQLInsert -Connection $Connection -InsertStatement "Insert Into FileInformationReplicate (FolderPath,Filename,LastWriteTime,CreateTime,FileSizeinKB) values ('$FolderP','$File',$LastWriteT,$CreateT,$FileSZ)" -Verbose
}

Close-SQLServerConnection -Connection $Connection
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which debugger are you using, Alvin? From which module are the commands `Connect-SQLServer`, `Invoke-SQLSelect`, and `Invoke-SQLInsert` coming?

Comment: @lit i have a module for select, insert and connection functions

Comment: Check the logfiles in the SQL Server by using SQL Server Management Studios.  The log file is in the explorer under Management.  Make sure you see the login from you PS script and check the User/Group that was used to login.

Comment: @jdweng, here is the error message i got from logs "Unknown,Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'ReportServerTempDB' with worker pool size [2]"

Comment: That's not related to this issue

You say you have a module for select, insert, and connect functions, is that something you've written yourself or got from an external source? If external, can you link to it, and if something you've written can you share? We can't possibly diagnose something if we don't have the method of the insert available to review as well

Comment: For start, instead of ```$Results += $DataArrayLine``` you probably want ```$DataArray += $DataArrayLine``` since that’s the one you’re iterating over to call ```Invoke-SQLInsert```…

Comment: Did error occur at time when you ran the PS script? The error is normal during startup of the database.  If it is occurring when you code is running it could mean the database crashed and automatically restarted.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239181/messages-about-parallel-redo

Comment: @mclayton, thank you for this, the script works now, appreciate the the help

Comment: You have a serious SQL injection issue. I suggest you use proper parameterized queries, and if those scripts don't support them then use better ones such as the DbaTools module.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Charlieface, i will take note of this. I'm new to powershell and still learning. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

the script is now working, below is the revised script applying the suggestion by @mclayton.

my mistake was i called $Results when calling the stored values in array for the next loop

```
 $Connection = Connect-SQLServer -InstanceName "Local\TestSchema" -DatabaseName "TestDB" -IntergratedSecurity $true

$Results = Invoke-SQLSelect -Connection $Connection -SelectStatement "Select * from [FileInformation]"

foreach ($i in $Results)
{
 $GetTest = $Results #| where-object {$_.id -eq 6}
write-host "ID:"$i.id
write-host "FolderPath:"$i.FolderPath
Write-host "File:"$i.FileName
Write-host "LastWriteT:"$i.LastWriteTime
Write-host "CreateT:"$i.CreateTime
Write-host "FileSZ:"$i.FileSizeinKB

}

$DataArray = @()
#adding to array

foreach ($i in $Results)
{

$DataArrayLine = new-object PSObject
$DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ID" -Value $i.id
$DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FolderP" -Value $i.FolderPath
$DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "File" -Value $i.FileName
$DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LastWriteT" -Value $i.LastWriteTime
$DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CreateT" -Value $i.CreateTime
$DataArrayLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FileSZ" -Value $i.FileSizeinKB
# Adding customer line to new customer array
$DataArray  += $DataArrayLine
}

$DataArray 


ForEach ($b in $DataArray )
{
$id = $b.id -as [int]
$FolderP = $b.FolderP
$File = $b.File
$LastWriteT = $b.LastWriteT -as [datetime]
$CreateT = $b.CreateT -as [datetime]
$FileSZ = $b.FileSZ

Invoke-SQLInsert -Connection $Connection -InsertStatement "Insert Into FileInformationReplicate (FolderPath,Filename,LastWriteTime,CreateTime,FileSizeinKB) values ('$FolderP','$File','$LastWriteT','$CreateT','$FileSZ')" -Verbose
}


Close-SQLServerConnection -Connection $Connection
```

Thank you everyone who commented in my question, appreciate the help